# IN by other column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to put a column in the `IN`?

Example:

```
SELECT tb1.*, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
          FROM tb2 
         WHERE id IN( tb1.ids_tb2 )) AS names
  FROM tb1
```

Column `tb1.ids_tb2` stores `"1,2,3"`

This is not working.

++++

I need 'ids_tb2' inside the IN

[Example Tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cfa9/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cfa9/1)

Ids_tb2 = 1,3,4
Names != Fruit1,Fruit3,Fruit4

tks

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Comma separated values... Don't store data like that. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Quick and dirty (very dirty) : WHERE instr(concat(tb1.ids_tb2,','),concat(id,','))>0

Comment: I need 'ids_tb2' inside the IN

[Example Tables sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cfa9/1)

Names = Fruit1,Fruit3,Fruit4

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is *not really ideal for this task*. In database design you should always preserve the 'atomicity' of data, i. e. you should never work with lists of ids in any column. Instead use a link table `lnk` like this

```
| gid | fid |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   3 |
|   1 |   4 |
|   2 |   1 |
|   2 |   5 |
```

Having such a structure you can then very easily do

```
SELECT grp , GROUP_CONCAT(name) fruits 
FROM tb1 
INNER JOIN lnk ON gid=grid
INNER JOIN tb2 ON frid=fid
GROUP BY grp
```

see [here (demo)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a50788/2/0).

The result will be

```
|  grp |               fruits |
|------|----------------------|
| Blue | Fruit1,Fruit3,Fruit4 |
|  Red |        Fruit1,Fruit5 |
```

Having said that - you *could* also do the following with your original database design (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cfa9/10/0)):

```
SELECT tb1.id,`group`,GROUP_CONCAT(name) fruits 
FROM tb1 
INNER JOIN tb2 ON FIND_IN_SET(tb2.id,ids_tb2)>0
GROUP BY `group`
```

Although I would not recommend doing this. Also you should not be using reserved SQL names for your columns like `group`, as you will always have to use back-ticks to mask them.

**Revisiting ...**
Actually, your initial approach *does also work*, you just have to replace your `IN (..)` clause by a `FIND_IN_SET(..)` function call like

```
SELECT tb1.*, 
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM tb2 
   WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tb2.id, tb1.ids_tb2)>0) names
FROM tb1
```

Comment: Yes, but existing code CRUD automatic and the list is generated from a view of mysql. =(

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple select in the in. Just like this:

```
SELECT tb1.*, 
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
      FROM tb2 
     WHERE id IN(select * from tb1.ids_tb2 )) AS names
FROM tb1
```

Comment: Would they not need to split the array for that field to get the IN to work?